# Libsourcey: webrtcrecorder.mp4 file is not generated

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, webrtc, x264, libsourcey

I am running WebRTC Native Video Recorder demo Application, but webrtcrecorder.mp4 file is not generated. As I have gone through some question and answers but unable to find the answer. I am getting some error

here is the command of cmake

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF     -DBUILD_MODULES=OFF    -DBUILD_APPLICATIONS=OFF \
   -DBUILD_SAMPLES=ON         -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF         -DWITH_WEBRTC=ON -DWITH_FFMPEG=ON    -DBUILD_MODULE_base=ON \
   -DBUILD_MODULE_crypto=ON   -DBUILD_MODULE_http=ON       -DBUILD_MODULE_json=ON               -DBUILD_MODULE_av=ON    \
   -DBUILD_MODULE_net=ON      -DBUILD_MODULE_socketio=ON   -DBUILD_MODULE_symple=ON             -DBUILD_MODULE_stun=ON   \
   -DBUILD_MODULE_turn=ON     -DBUILD_MODULE_util=ON       -DBUILD_MODULE_uv=ON                 -DBUILD_MODULE_webrtc=ON \
   -DBUILD_SAMPLES_webrtc=ON  -DWEBRTC_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/ubuntu/temp/webrtc-22215-ab42706-linux-x64/include \
   -DWEBRTC_LIBRARIES=/home/ubuntu/temp/webrtc-22215-ab42706-linux-x64/lib/ \
   -DWEBRTC_ROOT_DIR=/home/ubuntu/temp/webrtc-22215-ab42706-linux-x64    \
   -DBUILD_MODULE_openssl=ON   -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/ssl     -DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/ssl/lib/ \
   -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/
```

here are the logs of webrtcrecorder:

````
Client state changed from Closed to Connecting
13:31:54 [debug] [application.cpp(104)] Wait for shutdown
13:31:54 [debug] [signaler.cpp(116)] Client state changed from Connecting to Connected
13:31:54 [debug] [client.cpp(364)] On handshake: sid=_Wi06W8eF4GdOGn_AAAA, pingInterval=25000, pingTimeout=60000
13:31:54 [debug] [client.cpp(387)] Peer connected:videorecorder|_Wi06W8eF4GdOGn_AAAA
13:31:54 [debug] [signaler.cpp(116)] Client state changed from Connected to Online
13:31:59 [debug] [signaler.cpp(89)] Peer message: demo|Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB
13:31:59 [debug] [signaler.cpp(71)] Peer connected: Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB
13:31:59 [debug] [client.cpp(387)] Peer connected:demo|Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB
13:32:00 [debug] [signaler.cpp(89)] Peer message: demo|Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB
13:32:00 [debug] [peer.cpp(130)] Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB: Receive offer: v=0
o=- 7392103695987858658 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:ICgM
a=ice-pwd:hruHw+Fgaswb+slJ3/eE3Yad
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 B3:30:19:FA:91:57:CE:2B:7D:60:C4:16:27:FE:8E:CB:76:57:31:C6:75:72:72:87:36:C4:8E:30:91:01:27:D8
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:1294348972 cname:G/WgJ3Ijh9QR84NI
a=ssrc:1294348972 msid:je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd 30683b54-4aef-4c98-bf11-e9f497eddafd
a=ssrc:1294348972 mslabel:je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd
a=ssrc:1294348972 label:30683b54-4aef-4c98-bf11-e9f497eddafd
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 122 127 121 125 107 108 109 124 120 123 119 114
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:ICgM
a=ice-pwd:hruHw+Fgaswb+slJ3/eE3Yad
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 B3:30:19:FA:91:57:CE:2B:7D:60:C4:16:27:FE:8E:CB:76:57:31:C6:75:72:72:87:36:C4:8E:30:91:01:27:D8
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 x-google-profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:122 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:122 apt=102
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:121 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=125
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d0032
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:124 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:124 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:124 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack pli
a=fmtp:124 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640032
a=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:120 apt=124
a=rtpmap:123 red/90000
a=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:119 apt=123
a=rtpmap:114 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 3747062777 227800175
a=ssrc:3747062777 cname:G/WgJ3Ijh9QR84NI
a=ssrc:3747062777 msid:je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd e64ec0a4-3603-40d3-a6c6-01c5e60c79ef
a=ssrc:3747062777 mslabel:je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd
a=ssrc:3747062777 label:e64ec0a4-3603-40d3-a6c6-01c5e60c79ef
a=ssrc:227800175 cname:G/WgJ3Ijh9QR84NI
a=ssrc:227800175 msid:je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd e64ec0a4-3603-40d3-a6c6-01c5e60c79ef
a=ssrc:227800175 mslabel:je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd
a=ssrc:227800175 label:e64ec0a4-3603-40d3-a6c6-01c5e60c79ef

13:32:00 [debug] [peer.cpp(165)] Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB: On signaling state change: 3
13:32:00 [debug] [peer.cpp(225)] Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB: On add stream
13:32:00 [debug] [signaler.cpp(139)] -------onAddRemotestream---------
13:32:00 [debug] [peermanager.cpp(64)] Received offer: v=0
o=- 7392103695987858658 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:ICgM
a=ice-pwd:hruHw+Fgaswb+slJ3/eE3Yad
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 B3:30:19:FA:91:57:CE:2B:7D:60:C4:16:27:FE:8E:CB:76:57:31:C6:75:72:72:87:36:C4:8E:30:91:01:27:D8
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:1294348972 cname:G/WgJ3Ijh9QR84NI
a=ssrc:1294348972 msid:je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd 30683b54-4aef-4c98-bf11-e9f497eddafd
a=ssrc:1294348972 mslabel:je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd
a=ssrc:1294348972 label:30683b54-4aef-4c98-bf11-e9f497eddafd
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 122 127 121 125 107 108 109 124 120 123 119 114
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:ICgM
a=ice-pwd:hruHw+Fgaswb+slJ3/eE3Yad
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 B3:30:19:FA:91:57:CE:2B:7D:60:C4:16:27:FE:8E:CB:76:57:31:C6:75:72:72:87:36:C4:8E:30:91:01:27:D8
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 x-google-profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:122 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:122 apt=102
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:121 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=125
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d0032
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:124 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:124 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:124 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack pli
a=fmtp:124 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640032
a=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:120 apt=124
a=rtpmap:123 red/90000
a=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:119 apt=123
a=rtpmap:114 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 3747062777 227800175
a=ssrc:3747062777 cname:G/WgJ3Ijh9QR84NI
a=ssrc:3747062777 msid:je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd e64ec0a4-3603-40d3-a6c6-01c5e60c79ef
a=ssrc:3747062777 mslabel:je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd
a=ssrc:3747062777 label:e64ec0a4-3603-40d3-a6c6-01c5e60c79ef
a=ssrc:227800175 cname:G/WgJ3Ijh9QR84NI
a=ssrc:227800175 msid:je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd e64ec0a4-3603-40d3-a6c6-01c5e60c79ef
a=ssrc:227800175 mslabel:je7s7e9RhWY3cMVjVn8y0ipyOgJnTgu1bMYd
a=ssrc:227800175 label:e64ec0a4-3603-40d3-a6c6-01c5e60c79ef

13:32:00 [debug] [peer.cpp(329)] On SDP parse success
13:32:00 [debug] [peer.cpp(255)] Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB: Set local description
13:32:00 [debug] [peer.cpp(165)] Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB: On signaling state change: 0
13:32:00 [debug] [peer.cpp(329)] On SDP parse success
13:32:00 [debug] [peer.cpp(191)] Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB: On ICE gathering change: 1
13:32:00 [debug] [signaler.cpp(89)] Peer message: demo|Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB
13:32:00 [debug] [peermanager.cpp(85)] Received candidate: candidate:2999745851 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.56.1 60548 typ host generation 0 ufrag ICgM network-id 2
13:32:00 [debug] [peer.cpp(185)] Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB: On ICE connection change: 1
13:32:00 [debug] [signaler.cpp(89)] Peer message: demo|Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB
13:32:00 [debug] [peermanager.cpp(85)] Received candidate: candidate:564218470 1 udp 2122194687 100.64.100.204 60549 typ host generation 0 ufrag ICgM network-id 1 network-cost 10
13:32:00 [debug] [signaler.cpp(89)] Peer message: demo|Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB
13:32:00 [debug] [peermanager.cpp(85)] Received candidate: candidate:2999745851 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.56.1 60550 typ host generation 0 ufrag ICgM network-id 2
13:32:00 [debug] [signaler.cpp(89)] Peer message: demo|Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB
13:32:00 [debug] [peermanager.cpp(85)] Received candidate: candidate:564218470 1 udp 2122194687 100.64.100.204 60551 typ host generation 0 ufrag ICgM network-id 1 network-cost 10
13:32:00 [debug] [peer.cpp(191)] Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB: On ICE gathering change: 2
13:32:00 [debug] [signaler.cpp(89)] Peer message: demo|Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB
13:32:00 [debug] [peermanager.cpp(85)] Received candidate: candidate:4233069003 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.56.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag ICgM network-id 2
13:32:00 [debug] [signaler.cpp(89)] Peer message: demo|Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB
13:32:00 [debug] [peermanager.cpp(85)] Received candidate: candidate:1864545942 1 tcp 1518214911 100.64.100.204 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag ICgM network-id 1 network-cost 10
13:32:00 [debug] [signaler.cpp(89)] Peer message: demo|Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB
13:32:00 [debug] [peermanager.cpp(85)] Received candidate: candidate:4233069003 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.56.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag ICgM network-id 2
13:32:00 [debug] [signaler.cpp(89)] Peer message: demo|Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB
13:32:00 [debug] [peermanager.cpp(85)] Received candidate: candidate:1864545942 1 tcp 1518214911 100.64.100.204 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag ICgM network-id 1 network-cost 10
13:32:15 [debug] [peer.cpp(185)] Ivv61MFbOi96l__ZAAAB: On ICE connection change: 4```
````

Error:

```
[libx264 @ 0x7f415c001600] invalid level_idc: 8
12:00:14 [error] [multiplexencoder.cpp(153)] Error: Cannot open the video codec: Generic error in an external library
12:00:14 [error] [streamrecorder.cpp(87)] Failed to init encoder: std::exception
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Well no, there's no entry for 8 in x264_levels here: http://git.videolan.org/?p=x264.git;a=blob_plain;f=common/tables.c;hb=HEAD and from a quick git log -S search there never was. You'll have to track down where the 8 is coming from.

Comment: I am not configuring x264 levels anywhere. here is the av format configuration: 
av::VideoCodec("H.264", "libx264", 1280, 720, 30, 2000000, 128000, "yuv420p"), 
av::AudioCodec("AAC", "libfdk_aac", 2, 44100, 64000, "s16"));

Comment: Well, by default profile level would be 0. So added level manually. now working fine, but getting segmentation fault after that

Comment: You might do better [raising an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/sourcey/libsourcey) I guess since you haven't found people who know this code here. But if you're able to investigate the stack trace and see what's gone wrong - maybe it's some more missing config? - that would be very useful.

Comment: @Rup I have raised an issue in Gitub, but no comments.